# Not able to refresh parent view on close of child window in MVC 4! I am using IE 8

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-8

I have a bytearray, which open in a new browser window. I opened the new window by giving `target=_blank` in `HTML.BeginForm`. Now the issue is that I am not able to refresh the parent view on close of child browser.

Razor code to open PDF in new window using `HTML.BeginForm` on form post:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GeneratePDFs", "Flights", FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_blank" }))
```

Here is the Javascript code to refresh the parent page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    debugger
    window.opener.location.reload();

    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This drives me crazy! Anyone please help me on this! I have been working on for 2 days to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Ok firstly, calm down! :p

You just need to add the following script on your child view

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $(window).on("unload", function() {
            window.opener.location.reload(true);
            window.close();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });

</script>
```

Basically it attaches an event to the child window with a callback function. So when the window is closed it refreshes the window that originally opened it!

Comment: It's not working! Just wanted to inform you that, child window opens PDF using MemoryStream object!  Here is the code! flightViewModel.PDFDocument.Read(flightViewModel.PDF);
                            pdfData = flightViewModel.PDF;
                            outputStream.Write(pdfData, 0, pdfData.Length);
                            outputStream.Position = 0;
                            return new FileStreamResult(outputStream, "application/pdf");

Comment: @AashishLad Apologies I didn't realise you were returning a FileStreamResult. The only thing I can think of is to return a view which displays the PDF inside in an object tag and use the above script.